# Enabling Android as USB host on Galaxy Nexus or Nexus 10

Tags: usb, usb-host-mode

I'm trying to develop applications that talk to USB devices, but nothing works. I installed a USB Host Diagnostics app, and it tells me that there's no OS support for device detection on the Galaxy Nexus or the Nexus 10. I'm running Android 4.2 on both.

I tried the AdbTest sample application, but that doesn't respond when I connect the devices together. I tried updating the files in `/system/etc/permissions` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices), but that doesn't do anything.

Can anyone get USB device detection to work on these devices? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics about n10, but I found out an issue with my n7. When I bought it I got USB OTG/host working, but now when I tried with 4.2 it does not work anymore!

I found out that it was configured incorrectly. If you check `/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml` you should see line `android.hardware.usb.host` in there, but after 4.2 upgrade it was not there anymore.

So for me it looks like the only way to get it working is to root the device. :-( I wonder why it has been taken out.

Comment: I have a Nexus 7 running 4.2.2. It is rooted mainly for USB OTG usage, which I am using quite well. Being curious about the XML, I could not find any entry related to host or USB in that file, but still OTG works.